# Как считывать данные с USB устройства (источника бесперебойного питания)?

Tags: c#

Есть источник бесперебойного питания, подключен он к двум компьютером одновременно и к одному по USB. Как мне при выключении электричества вырубить второй по сети? 
Я правильно понимаю,что надо получить данные с USB и потом командой по сети вырубить второй? Подскажите, куда мне копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сначала выяснить под каким классом usb регистрируется бесперебойник в системе. Это может быть эмулятор com-порта, hid-совместимое устройство или что-то более экзотическое. К каждом случае протокол обмена будет разный.

HID-устройства регистрируют в системе несколько (обычно по одному) потоков ввода и вывода. Отправка/прием данных в этих потоках осуществляются usb-пакетами. Получение списка потоков, прием и отправка пакетов реализуются библиотекой для работы с USB. Как конкретно в C# - не знаю.

Содержимое пакетов стандарт вообще никак не регламентирует. Если повезет, то удастся нагуглить спецификацию по вашей модели, если нет - то придется заниматься реверс-инженерном.

Детальная спецификация, правда на английском, свободно доступна на сайте консорциума http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/

Comment: Батарея ИБП HID пишет

Answer (score 1):

Если устройство системой определяется как ИБП (корректно установленны драйвера и в трее значок батареи), то проще отслеживать через [BatteryChargeStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus.batterychargestatus.aspx)

пример:

```
string stringBatteryChargeStatus = "";
        switch (SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus)
        {
            case BatteryChargeStatus.Charging:
                stringBatteryChargeStatus = "BatteryChargeStatus: Charging";
                break;
            case BatteryChargeStatus.Critical:
                stringBatteryChargeStatus = "BatteryChargeStatus: Critical";
                break;
            case BatteryChargeStatus.High:
                stringBatteryChargeStatus = "BatteryChargeStatus: High";
                break;
            case BatteryChargeStatus.Low:
                stringBatteryChargeStatus = "BatteryChargeStatus: Low";
                break;
            case BatteryChargeStatus.NoSystemBattery:
                stringBatteryChargeStatus = "BatteryChargeStatus: NoSystemBattery";
                break;
            case BatteryChargeStatus.Unknown:
                stringBatteryChargeStatus = "BatteryChargeStatus: Unknown";
                break;
        }
```

при отсутствии ИБП (или другого резервоно источника питания, например аккумулятора в ноутбуке) статус будет "NoSystemBattery", если ИБП присутствует, то при полностью заряженном состоянии статус будет "High", при разрядке постепенно будет переходить на "Low" и затем на "Critical"

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: извиняюсь, добавил пример

Comment: Огромное спасибо!